# Is it a good practice to call a method of a child component inside the parent's template in Angular?

Tags: angular, angular6

I have a parent component which basically is a form composed by two child components, each of them composed by a bunch of `inputs`. Here's the parent component template:

```
<!-- Bunch of user selected filters -->
<app-filters #filters>
</app-filters>

<!-- Bunch of user selected grouping options -->
<app-grouping-options #groupingOptions>
</app-grouping-options>

<!-- Emit an event with the composed query so
other component can recover and show the data
to the user -->
<button (click)="emitQuery(filters.getFilteringCriteria(), groupingOptions.getGroupingCriteria())">Search</button>
```

The part I'm interested in is the `filters.getFilteringCriteria()` and the `groupingOptions.getGroupingOptionsCriteria()` method calls. I'm not sure if this is a good practice at all, specially because it seems to break the intended flow of data: *from parents to children through property binding, and from children to parent through events*. But I really don't know how to proceed in this case, because the functionality of searching is indeed a method, not a property.

Apart from that, which is the best approach to refer to a child component? Through template variables or using `@ViewChild`?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I'll try to make the components like < app-filters (onChangeFilter)="filter=$event">< /app-filters> and <app-grouping-options (onChangeGrouping)="grouping=$event" >< /app-grouping-options>. For me is more readable. Think that in the future you can change the <app-grouping-options> by another component (or none) or someone want to refresh not only when you click the button else in any change of filter

Comment: @Eliseo That's a good idea, +1.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It isn't the best practice because it means your components are tightly coupled (this means that your first component relies on the other 2).

If you want to use the best practice, rely on `@Input` for your filters (changing the filters in the child will change the filters in the parent), and `@Output` for the grouping options (use an event emitter to propagate the event to the parent).

Now don't get me wrong : it's totally fine to do what you did. It just means that will have to go extra miles to make your components generic, if you want to do so.

If not, then keep this, even if people on SOF tell you not to. You're not *forced* to reuse components !

Comment: Well, I undertand what you said, but I think they are reusable anyway, the problem is that, in this way, the next developer who has to maintain the code has to remember calling `filters.getFilteringCriteria()` and `groupingOptions.getGroupingCriteria()` methods. But if I change it according to what you said... I don't know. The `filters` component has about 20 comboboxes, so maybe it's better to get the user's selection calling a method instead of connecting it to the parent component through property binding.

Comment: As I said, this is the best practice, not the *must-do* practice. Feel free to do whatever you want, I'm just answering your question !

Comment: Thsi remark goes on the original question, not the answer, could you please move it ?

Comment: Sorry, just did it